# Error instancing JwtHelper in Angular2 application

Tags: angular, jwt

I am getting a strange exception when trying to instance a new JwtHelper in Angular2. This has had me stumped for ages due to the very cryptic error. When I try and include JwtHelper its thowing an unexpected number error, I thought the error was this line:

```
this.jwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
```

However I think now its just the actual import which generates the JS to require(anguluar2-jwt) I have checked the modules folder and its there so I have no idea whats going on, this is the error in the developer console::

```
(index):72 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected number
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:4000/app/app.module.js:21:22)
```

the compiled JS is this:

```
var angular2_jwt_1 = require("angular2-jwt");
```

my package.json is using this version:

```
"angular2-jwt": "0.1.25",
```

and finally my import is:

```
import { JwtHelper } from "angular2-jwt";
```

Please let me know any other source that would assist in identifying this problem! Also character 22 of the compiled JS is the 'r' of require("ang....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this question as I atleast figured out what the problem was.  I have decided to switch dependency management from SystemJS and Gulp to Angular-cli however so my solution does not copy and paste well as an answer.
As to what the message:

```
(index):72 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected number
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Means I discovered it was as simple as a missing source, I was running in development mode so the actual JS file angular-jwt.js was not being bundled and included on index.html.  The error message was very unhelpful.